# Python one-liner with input and conditional?

Tags: python

Is there a way to use the ternary operator in conjunction with an input to assign something to a variable in one shot?

The more verbose way:

```
# assume this happened a while back.
myVariable = "user: "

# I'd like to get these two lines down to one.
myInputResult = input('Enter something, or just hit Enter for the default: ')
myVariable += "the user typed: " + myInputResult if myInputResult != '' else 'the user did not type anything'
```

What I'd need to be able to do is reference the value from the `input()` function without first assigning it to a variable.

I've seen a technique in other languages, but it doesn't look like Python supports returning the value assigned when you treat the assignment like a variable:

```
myVariable += "the user typed " + x if (x = input("Enter something or nothing: ")) != '' else "the user did not type anything"
```

doesn't work.

Note that even if `input` can return a default, this isn't sufficient as the static text differs when the user entered nothing.

The variable method is fine, but I'm just looking for a more concise method of writing the code if it's possible.

Python 3, btw.

Comment: ...but why are you trying to save keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn’t have inline assignment. You could write a function that applies a transformation to truthy values and leave falsy values like the empty string unchanged (this is the “lite” version of an `Optional.map`-type function):

```
def map_true(fn, value):
    return value and fn(value)
```

and use it as follows:

```
myVariable += (
    map_true("the user typed {}".format, input("Enter something or nothing: ")) or
    "the user did not type anything")
```

but that’s not a huge improvement.